# SQL query for sales report by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table of sales leads:

```
CREATE TABLE "lead" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "marketer" varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    "date_set" varchar(500) NOT NULL
)
;
INSERT INTO lead VALUES (1, 'Joe', '05/01/13');
INSERT INTO lead VALUES (2, 'Joe', '05/02/13');
INSERT INTO lead VALUES (3, 'Joe', '05/03/13');
INSERT INTO lead VALUES (4, 'Sally', '05/03/13');
INSERT INTO lead VALUES (5, 'Sally', '05/03/13');
INSERT INTO lead VALUES (6, 'Andrew', '05/04/13');
```

I want to produce a report that summarizes the number of records each marketer has for each day.  It should look like this:

```
| MARKETER | 05/01/13 | 05/02/13 | 05/03/13 | 05/04/13 |
--------------------------------------------------------
|      Joe |        1 |        1 |        1 |        0 |
|    Sally |        0 |        0 |        2 |        1 |
|   Andrew |        0 |        0 |        0 |        1 |
```

What's the SQL query to produce this?

I have this example set up on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eb27a/1

Comment: Do you want as many columns as there are distinct dates in the table? isn't that an odd output for a report?

Comment: I want there to be as many columns as there are dates in a monthly.  This is for generating weekly and monthly reports.

Comment: I guess you have no other way but to do what ntalbs has answered, you should list every day.

Comment: +1 for including the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure SQL cannot produce such structure (it is two dimensional, but sql return plain list of records).

You could make query like this:

```
select marketer, date_set, count(id) 
from lead
group by marketer, date_set;
```

And vizualise this data by your reporting system.

Comment: This is the raw data that I need.  I have a Web framework connected to the database that can take the output of this query and generate the table I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
select
  marketer,
  count(case when date_set = '05/01/13' then 1 else null end) as "05/01/13",
  count(case when date_set = '05/02/13' then 1 else null end) as "05/02/13",
  count(case when date_set = '05/03/13' then 1 else null end) as "05/03/13",
  count(case when date_set = '05/04/13' then 1 else null end) as "05/04/13"
from lead
group by marketer
```

Comment: +1 I wrote a similar query but with 0 instead of null and it does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: @jurgenreza When you use 0 instead of null, you should you `sum` function. `count` function counts any values including zeros.

Comment: Anyway, this query is not flexible. @Parandroid's way is generally better than this.